# Create tables and entities with Doctrine2 based on schema declaration

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, command-line, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get `Doctrine2` and `Zend Framework` working together. So far I have been able to autoload `Doctrine2` and connect to my database.

I am now looking forward creating my tables using a schema declaration in `yml` :

```
Doctrine\Entities\User:
    type: entity
    table: core_user
    columns:
        id:
            primary: true
            autoincrement: true
            type: integer(11)
            notnull: true
        name:
            type: string
            notnull: true
            default: ''
        middle_name:
            type: string
            default: ''
        last_name:
            type: string
            notnull:true
            default: ''
        username:
            type: varchar(16)
            default: ''
        email:
            type: string
            notnull: true
            default: ''
        role_id:
            type: integer
        date_creation:
            type: timestamp
        version:
            type: timestamp
```

I have been able to get the command line working, but I can't get it to create the tables in my database.

I am using a standard `Zend Framework` folder structure

```
+-- Application
      +-- configs
      +-- controllers
      +-- doctrine
          +-- Schema
              +-- schema.yml
          +-- Entities
          cli-config.php
      +-- layouts
      +-- models
      +-- modules
      +-- view
      bootstrap.php
+-- Public
+-- Library
      +-- Doctrine2
+-- Tests
```

My schema declaration is in `Application/doctrine/Schema/schema.yml` and I am looking to create my database `tables` and my `Entities` from it.

When I try to run the command `doctrine orm:schema-tool:create` I get the following message : `No Metadata Classes to process.` and I am wondering why.

Am I on the right way of getting it working, or should I define manually my entities and then try to create my tables from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check configurations in `cli-config.php`.
You should use YAML driver:

```
// $config instanceof Doctrine\ORM\Configuration
$driver = new YamlDriver(array('/path/to/files'));
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
```

More in [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/yaml-mapping.html).